# How can I sync my Yahoo! Calendar with Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, calendar

I want to sync my Yahoo! Calendar with my Google Calendar account.

I did this by getting an iCal link within Yahoo! Calendar and then adding it to Google Calendar, but it does not seem to fetch content from that address.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you access the iCal link directly in your browser (pasting it into the location field), what do you get? An error message, or an iCal file?

Comment: I get an iCal file, correctly.

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP here. I am trying to embed a calendar into my website but Google Calendar's functionality is a bit lacking. Yahoo's is fine, but doesn't have native embed abilities. So I'm trying to sync my Yahoo calendar with Google Calendars. Every website and video I can find has the exact same instructions and I'm following them to the "T". The only catch is, Google Calendars is not fetching any events from the yahoo calendar. Google just shows it as blank. So when I found this solution, I thought it was the answer to all my problems.
I'm adding "caldav" to the url lik

Comment: to the url like this: http://caldav.calendars.yahoo... but it is not working for me. Google gives me the following error: The address that you provided did not contain a calendar in a valid iCal or GData format. I've been going round and round with this for a few hours. Can someone please help?

Comment: @user42393, that should be `caldav.calendar.yahoo`, not `caldav.calendars.yahoo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must try the host name as '**caldav**.calendar.yahoo.com', instead of 'calendar.yahoo.com'. This is how I solved it.

Comment: Note that simply editing the URL once the calendar has been added isn't enough. One has to re-Add by URL.

Comment: Hmm, newly added events to the Yahoo Calendar aren't showing up in Google Calendar.

Comment: I tried creating a `goo.gl` short URL from Yahoo's caldav URL and adding that to Google Calendar. It, too, didn't have the new event. Recreating the Yahoo's caldav URL (thereby invalidating the old one) and adding that imports the new event. It looks like Yahoo isn't pushing new events.

Comment: Hmm, OTOH, when I use my browser to get the ICS directly from the caldav URL, it does have the new event. I'm not sure what's happening at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to sync Yahoo with Google to have it on my mobile. The best solution I found, after 8 hours of research, was to install the [SolCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.daum.android.solcalendar) app on my Android. There I can see and edit all calendars (for me Yahoo and Google). Using Lightning (on Thunderbird) did not work.

Comment: The Asker never mentioned using a smartphone. It appears that a pure web app solution is wanted.